# ionic2 Streaming Media is not working

Tags: android, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I'm using the streaming media plugin in my ionic2 application.
this is my code:

```
let option:StreamingAudioOptions = {
          successCallback: () => { console.log('Audio played') },
          errorCallback: (e) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null,2)) }
      }
 this.streamingMedia.playAudio('http://sounddible.com/grab.php?id=2196&type=mp3',option);
```

the errorCallback return "**Class not found**"

Any help for explain the reason of this log

Thanks.

Comment: i try this audio URL is not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingAudioOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) {}

      startAudio(){
        let options: StreamingAudioOptions = {
          successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
          errorCallback: (e) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null,2)) },
          initFullscreen:false,
        };
          this.streamingMedia.playAudio('YOUR_URL', options);
      }
```

Comment: initFullscreen is not working, initFullscreen:false should be displayed in small screen